# Retrieve Elementor Form Values from Form Control in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin, that's meant to simplify the integration of Salesforce to an Elementor Form. So far, so good, I've managed to get a couple of things to work correctly, such as the Salesforce Integration, and the Custom Salesforce section on the "Actions After Submit" part of the elementor form editor.
[image]

Now, the tricky part is retrieving the form fields already designed from the elementor form ("Name", "Email", "Message") and displaying them in the dropdown, for me to map these fields to a salesforce table.

Any ideas on how I can implement this?

salesforce-form-control.php

```
<?php

// namespace Salesforce_Elementor_Addon;
use Salesforce_Elementor_Addon\Salesforce;


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

class Salesforce_Form_Action_Elementor extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Action_Base {

    private $salesforce;
    private $error;
    private $records;
    private $tableOptions;


    public function __construct()
    {
        error_log("\n\n1. Form Action Constructor Called ========" . "\n\n", 3, ABSPATH . 'error_log');
        $this->tableOptions = $this->getTableOptions();
    }

    public function get_name() {
        return 'salesforce';
    }

    public function get_label() {
        return esc_html__( 'Salesforce', 'elementor-forms-salesforce' );
    }

    public function register_settings_section( $widget ) {
        $widget->start_controls_section(
            'section_salesforce_object',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Save Values To Salesforce Object', 'elementor-pro' ),
                'condition' => [
                    'submit_actions' => $this->get_name(),
                ],
            ]
        );

        $widget->add_control(
            'content',
            [
                'type' => 'salesforce_mapping_form  );



        $widget->end_controls_section();
    }

    public function on_export( $element ) {}

    public function run( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
        //Code to Submit form to Salesforce

    }
}
```

form-control.php //with dropdowns to map the fields

```
<?php

/**
 * Elementor emoji one area control.
 *
 * A control for displaying a textarea with the ability to add emojis.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
class SalesforceMappingFormControl extends \Elementor\Base_Data_Control
{

    /**
     * Get control type.
     *
     * Retrieve the control type, in this case `salesforce_mapping_form`.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @return string Control type.
     */
    public function get_type()
    {
        return 'salesforce_mapping_form';
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue  control scripts and styles.
     *
     * Used to register and enqueue custom scripts and styles used by the emoji one
     * area control.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function enqueue()
    {
        
        wp_register_script('salesforce-form-control', plugins_url('../assets/js/salesforce.js', dirname(__FILE__)), ['emojionearea'], '1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('salesforce-form-control');
    }

    /**
     * Get  default settings.
     *
     * Retrieve the default settings of the emoji one area control. Used to return
     * the default settings while initializing the emoji one area control.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access protected
     * @return array Control default settings.
     */
    protected function get_default_settings()
    {
        return [
            
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Render emoji one area control output in the editor.
     *
     * Used to generate the control HTML in the editor using Underscore JS
     * template. The variables for the class are available using `data` JS
     * object.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function content_template()
    {
        $control_uid = $this->get_control_uid();
?>

    

        <!-- <div class="elementor-control-input-wrapper">
                <textarea id="<?php // echo esc_attr( $control_uid ); 
                                            ?>" class="elementor-control-tag-area" rows="{{ data.rows }}" data-setting="{{ data.name }}" placeholder="{{ data.placeholder }}"></textarea>
            </div> -->
        <div class="elementor-control elementor-control-table elementor-control-type-select elementor-label-inline elementor-control-separator-default" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px;">
            <div class="elementor-control-content">
                <div class="elementor-control-field">
                    <label for="elementor-control-default-c1037" class="elementor-control-title">Select Object</label>
                    <div class="elementor-control-input-wrapper elementor-control-unit-5">
                        <select id="elementor-control-default-c1037" data-setting="table">
                            <option value="AIApplication">AIApplication</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="elementor-control-field-description">Map Form Fields</div>
        <div class="elementor-control elementor-control-table elementor-control-type-select elementor-label-inline elementor-control-separator-default">
            <div class="elementor-control-content">
                <div class="elementor-control-field ">
                    <div class="elementor-control-input-wrapper elementor-control-unit-5" style="margin: 5px;">
                        <select id="elementor-control-default-c1037" data-setting="table">
                            <option value="AIApplication">Test option</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elementor-control-input-wrapper elementor-control-unit-5" style="margin: 5px;">
                        <select id="elementor-control-default-c1037" data-setting="table">
                            <option value="AIApplication">Test option</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<?php
    }


}
```